# Is there a required minimum oven temperature for baking matzah?

Tags: halacha, matzah

Are there halachically required minimum temperatures for baking matzah? This Jewish [instructional websites](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/recipe/matzah-baking-an-18-minute-project/) says they should be baked at "extremely high temperatures" such as "600° to 800° F".

However the Shulchan Arukh in this quote doesn't mention any minimum degree requirements.

> A tafka (meaning one of the tiles used to cover the roof, "kofi" in the vernacular) made of new ceramic is permitted *whether one fired it from inside or outside.* This is because the fire burns under it, and even though the flame does not reach its top, it boils and the bread cooks instantly and does not rise. However, firing is needed at the beginning, whether it is used in an oven, a frying pan, a stew-pot without water, or on the ground. However, some forbid putting [the bread] on first and then firing, and it is good to be careful. There is one who says that we should stop those who make thick cakes in embers (meaning hot ashes, tzinironi in the vernacular).

Source: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Shulchan_Aruch/Orach_Chaim/461

The Shulchan Arukh seems to be concerned that there is a minimum temperature, but it doesn't seem to be concerned that there is a minimum number. Rather it seems concerned that the matzah cooks all the way through, and it is assuming that one is cooking matzah that is soft and thicker than a finger breadth, we know this to be the case because of how it discusses fulfilling the mitzvah of matzah.

> One fulfills his obligation with matzo that is baked enough so that no threads can be pulled from it.

The matzah is finished when one pulls apart the matzah and there are no uncooked threads, which cannot happen in the matzah we have now, the matzah that is probably cooked between 600-800 degrees. At least, this is the argument [this website](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rD2_4iZImC8J:www.realmatza.com/ovens-too-hot.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) makes, claiming that ovens in contrast could be too hot, stating that poskim ruled that one could matzah on paper, which burns at 392 degrees Fahrenheit.

The same argument that an oven shouldn't be too hot because it might cook the outside instantaneously while leaving the center uncooked is made in [this article.](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol17Zivotofsky.pdf)

> This development might
>   have been related to the changing nature of ovens. Rabbi Yosef Eliyahu
>   Henkin (Lev Ivra, p. 40) makes a very important point about the oven
>   temperature. He says that if, while baking thick matzah, the oven is too
>   hot the outside will burn and the inside will still be unbaked. And, he
>   suggests, the halakhik indicators related to ḥimutz (browned outside and
>   stringy dough) won't help because they are valid only with ovens at lower
>   temperature, as were used in talmudic times. This is less of a problem for
>   the baking of thin matzot, but he cautions that the oven temperature
>   should nonetheless not be too hot. He says that this is all based on experience
>   and it is worth noting that he lived among Georgian Jews for many
>   years.

Yet one of the leading halachic authorities has ruled in the following ways:

> Rav Moshe Feinstein (Igrot Moshe OC 1:153) was asked about baking Matza on a stove-top and rules that the temperature must be at least hot enough "that straw would burn" or else we would have to worry that it is Chametz. He notes that the "classical" cooking temperatures of Yad Soledet Bo (~150°F) or boiling (212°F) are definitely insufficient.

Taking all these sources at face value would lead one to think there is contradicting information, or that there are two sets of rules: One set of rules for thick soft matzah, and possibly another set for thin dry matzah.

So with all of these factors considered, is there truly a certain minimum baking temperature for matzah?

Comment: Did you just plagiarize me in a post I answered??

Comment: Given that recent edits violate  http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1231/759 by invalidating an answer below, I'm putting this on hold until the q is adjusted in a way the OP agrees with.

Comment: @DoubleAA, shouldn't the question just be reverted to where it was when it was answered?

Comment: @IsaacMoses i would normally agree with you, but perhaps maybe my answer should be closed. Because i feel that while DoubleAAs answer was valid, it didn't really encompass the question i was actually asking, which is a question coming from conflicting information as my new edits shows.

Comment: @Aaron, you wrote a question that did not require closure and that got an answer that members of the community consider valuable. The question should be restored to where it was when the answer made sense in its context, so that that value remains extant. If you want to ask a follow-up question, explicitly referring to information you learned in the answer here, you certainly can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35978/discussion-between-isaac-moses-and-aaron).

Comment: As I commented elsewhere, I don't think you're reading the Shulchan Aruch correctly. It does not mention a minimum temperature, just that the cooking surface needs to be already ready. The bread certainly does not cook instantly and doesn't need to.

Comment: @MichoelR Correct. You can even cook with a roof shingle as long as the fire is already started. The real gist of it is that you need to make sure whatever you are cooking with will for sure cook the thickness of bread you want to make. And whether it's an oven or a saj, it needs to be ore heated

Comment: @MichoelR *pre-heated

Answer (score 5):

As you note in the Shulchan Arukh (OC 461:2), a temperature which is too low (and is not "boils and cooks instantly [such that] the bread doesn't rise") is problematic as the dough will just rise quicker in the warm environment whilst not cooking.

Rav Moshe Feinstein (Igrot Moshe OC 1:153) was asked about baking Matza on a stove-top and rules that the temperature must be at least hot enough "that straw would burn" or else we would have to worry that it is Chametz. He notes that the "classical" cooking temperatures of Yad Soledet Bo (~150°F) or boiling (212°F) are definitely insufficient.

The ignition point of straw is probably not a very precise number (varying based on the kind of grass and the moisture content) but I've seen estimates of 500°F. Thus 600°F from your article seems like a reasonable practical minimum.

Comment: Can you source at what temperature straw burns? Because i'm finding information that straw can burn at 200 degrees farenheit. And what are the lowest estimates you've seen?

Comment: @Aaron The two numbers I saw were 220C (=430F) and 550F. Closed the links already :/ Perhaps ask on Chemistry.SE? Like I said though there's definitely going to be variation. Straw that's dried for weeks will burn easier than green grass, seemingly.

Comment: @Aaron I'll note that the measure of "straw burns" is also used in the context of Libbun Kal (see [OC 551:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%93)) which is given [here for instance](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/hotel_kashering.php) as 550F. R Moshe doesn't explicitly connect the two though.

Comment: i do not find your argument compelling that the Shulchan Arukh is making a statement of facts that any oven that doesn't boil and cook instantly is problematic. But rather it is stating that this "tafka" oven can be fired from inside or outside because it cooks instantly and so therefore there isn't a concern. This seems to be the plain meaning as the indicator that matzah has been fulfilled a few sections over has nothing to do with oven temperature but only whether or not matzah cooks all the way through.

Comment: Which would mean that rather than being concerned that the temperature needs to be a certain mathematical minimum, it is concerned with a minimum temperature that would cook the dough all the way through. "Rabbi Yosef Eliyahu
Henkin (Lev Ivra, p. 40) makes a very important point about the oven
temperature. He says that if, while baking thick matzah, the oven is too
hot the outside will burn and the inside will still be unbaked. "

Comment: @Aaron You are quoting lots of things but I see no logical flow to your comment.  The Shulchan Arukh is clear that too low is problematic. That's why you have to preheat the oven. I don't know why you are referencing how to tell if dough is baked. I agree dough needs to be baked. No one thinks unbaked dough can be used for the Mitzva.

Comment: Rather than leave this in the comments i will change the question to reflect and make things more clear. Though your source is really valuable. And there is another question here regarding frying matzah that i think your source would make an excellent answer to the question.

Comment: @Aaron If editing the question, beware our standing policy http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1231/759

Comment: i saw your comment after i had finished editing the question, i will go back and look at my edits to see if i can edit in a way that satisfies the policy

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think you're reading the Shulchan Aruch correctly. To me it seems to say that the cooking surface has to be hot already, so that the cooking _begins instantly_ and there is no time gap where chimutz could occur. It doesn't give a minimum temperature, it just says that it has to be hot now.

Comment: @MichoelR The quoted temperatures are from Igros Moshe, not the ShA.

Comment: I understand and won't try to argue w IgM. But I don't think the ShA says "too low is problematic". It is interesting that even the part about not cooking in hot ashes, the Gr"a says "שלא ידבק דבר ויעכב האפייה כנ"ל
" - _in case something sticks to it and blocks cooking_ - something like the fear of folded matzah. He's not satisfied that maybe it isn't hot enough.