# When does the 18 minute limit for dough to become chametz end?

Tags: food, passover, matzah

I know that the 18 minute thing is up for debate (time for 1 mil, whether continually working dough can indefinitely extend it, temperature dependence etc.), but at what part of the process can a dough no longer become chametz? When it completely finishes baking?

If something becomes chametz through fermentation, I would guess that once the microorganisms are dead it can no longer become chametz, but that understanding of fermentation is a relatively recent thing, so how is it normally defined?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Jacob and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68421/759 Bake it on high and then it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Shulchan Arukh OC 461:3

> מצה שנאפית עד שאם פורסין אותה אין חוטין נמשכים ממנה יוצאים בה:
>   *הגה: ויש ליזהר שלא ללקחה מן התנור קודם לכן ולהחזירה כי תוכל לבוא לידי חימוץ*
>
> Matza that was baked until if you cut it no strings of dough pull from it, one fulfills his obligation with it. *Gloss: and one should be careful not to take it from the oven before then and return it because it may come to ferment.*